# Pimcore where does code go

Tags: pimcore

All the examples show random pimcore code; however, I have found no explanation of where the code goes - or a complete example. I do not use pimcore for the cms. I am only interested in the object management. The code I am trying to wrte is to export objects e.g. into csv or xml.

Thanks ~

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a plugin as suggested by Johan, but a quicker way is to just put the files into the /website/lib/Website folder. This folder is already added to the autoloader so you don't need to do anything else.

For example create an ObjectExporter.php under /website/lib/Website folder with this content:

```
<?php
namespace Website;

class ObjectExporter
{
    public function exportObjects()
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Then you can either instantiate this class in your controller action or in a CLI script. Controller actions are within /website/controllers folder and they need to be called through http: http://localhost?controller=default&action=default

Example: /website/controllers/DefaultController.php

```
<?php
class DefaultController extends Website_Controller_Action {
    public function defaultAction () {
        $this->disableViewAutoRender();

        $objectExporter = new Website\ObjectExporter();
        $objectExporter->exportObjects();
    }
}
```

(You could also add your whole code directly into action, but that would be a bit ugly solution, it of course depends)

But better and quickest way to approach such tasks is with the CLI scripts.
I like to use the /website/var/cli folder (you need to create it manually, but the  /website/var folder is excluded in .htaccess by default which makes it practical for such use cases).

Example: /website/var/cli/export-objects.php

```
<?php
$workingDirectory = getcwd();
chdir(__DIR__);
include_once("../../../pimcore/cli/startup.php");
chdir($workingDirectory);

$objectExporter = new Website\ObjectExporter();
$objectExporter->exportObjects();
```

Then just run it by issuing this command in your command line:

```
php website/var/cli/export-objects.php
```

In case you wish to add special UI elements to the Pimcore backend, the way to go is with building an extension as suggested by Johan.

Igor

Answer (score 0):

Here is a primcore example to export a list of object into a csv file

```
private function csvAction(){
$this->disableLayout();
$this->disableViewAutoRender();

$obj_list = new YourObject_List();
$obj_list->load();

/* @var $obj Object_YourObject */
$out = array();

foreach($obj_list as $obj){
    $entry = array();
    $entry["key"] = $obj->getKey();

    $entry["Field 1"] = $obj->getField1();
    $entry["Field 2"] = $obj->getField2();
    $entry["Field 3"] = $obj->getField3();
    $out[]=$entry;
}

$this->_helper->Csv($out, "produkt");
}
```

Comment: I really appreviate your response; however, where does this code go. And how to run it? I am fluent with php, but where do I put this code in pimcore file system?

Comment: this is a function in an Controller. Hence the name "csvAction".

Answer (score 0):

You could either create a new Plugin using admin function

Extras -> Extensions -> Create new Plugin
Add name Test
Activate plugin in list at Extras -> Extensions

You can then add the action above to plugins/Test/controllers/IndexController.php

It's also possible to add controller code in website/controllers, there is already a default controller there.

/Johan