# How to export objects into pimcore to an Xml

Tags: pimcore

Hi Guys Since I'm new to pimcore I don't have any idea how to export objects of a class to an xml file . I want you to tell the solution step by step since I don't know much about the way pimcore works

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard / built-in way to achieve what you want.

You could build a simple export script. First, get a list of objects
(see: https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE4/Object+Lists )
and then generate the XML ... basically:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

$objList = new Object\Myclassname\Listing();
foreach ($objList as $obj) {

    $item = $xml->addChild('item');
    $item->addChild('name', $obj->getName());
    $item->addChild('description', $obj->getDescription());
}

print($xml->asXML());
```

Please note:

- This sample assumes you have a "Myclassname" Objectclass with the simple fields "name" and "description"
- This is very inefficient for large amounts of objects, as the xml is generated in-memory

Please take a look at these ressources, too:

- https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE4/External+System+Interaction
- CLI https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16854341

Comment: Hi I don't know where to put script file and how to start means where I should write code and to place those code could you give me sample hint

Comment: Please take a look at the provided resources - it is all in there: https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16854341
"Autoloaded commands" ... "It must be placed in one of the namespaces listed above (e.g. Website\Console\Command\AwesomeCommand in /website/lib/Website/Console/Command/AwesomeCommand.php)" ... 
"get a list of all registered commands: 
 php pimcore/cli/console.php" - and so on.

Comment: Hi I followed the steps mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007816/pimcore-where-does-code-go    link  but when I am hitting the http://localhost?controller=default&action=default Iam getting a page "It seems that the page you were trying to find isn't around anymore." tell me  where I am going wrong

Comment: Okay. This is a different approach (HTTP instead of CLI). If you want to go the Controller/Action way, take a look at the Quick Start Bundle https://www.pimcore.org/en/resources/download and https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE4/Quick+Start+Guide . You need to get at least a bit familiar with Pimcore development - i can not provide you with a fully implemented solution - sorry.

Comment: did you just created one file for the whole thing and where you put that code and how u run it Iam done with coding but don't know how to run it

Comment: I do not mean to be rude - but did you take a look at the documentation and the sample code i referenced? If you want to run a script by opening an URL with a browser, you need to create/use a Controller/Action as described in the docs.

Comment: Good news! would you be so kind to accept my answer, if that really helped you? Thanks!